# Register RuntimeHints for Collections EmptyList class not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, graalvm-native-image, spring-native

I have the following method and a Cacheable annotation on top of that.

```
@Cacheable(value = "autosuggest", key = "#term", unless = "#result.size()==0")
    @Override
    public List<AutoSuggestUser> autoSuggestUsers(String term) {
        if (term.length() <= 3)
            return Collections.emptyList();
        ....
}
```

When I convert it to native image , I get the following error when function returns an EmptyList.

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1029E: A problem occurred when trying to execute method 'size' on object of type 'java.util.Collections$EmptyList': 'Problem invoking method: public int java.util.Collections$EmptyList.size()'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:146)
    at java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:775)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixPlatformThreads.java:203)
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.AccessException: Problem invoking method: public int java.util.Collections$EmptyList.size()
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:143)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:139)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public int java.util.Collections$EmptyList.size() accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @2055833f
    at java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtils.java:574)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:138)
    ... 71 more
```

I have added a runtime hint to register EmptyList class but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
    static class MyRuntimeHints implements RuntimeHintsRegistrar {

        @Override
        public void registerHints(RuntimeHints hints, ClassLoader classLoader) {
hints.reflection().registerType(TypeReference.of("java.util.Collections$EmptyList"),
                    builder -> builder.withMembers(MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_METHODS));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding below hints

```
        // Register Type Hints for class and interface since size() of EmptyList class
            // is not accessible because
            // JAVA Module system denies that access ; hence to circumvent that , we should
            // add hints for both interface and implementing class
            // so that Spring can call class methods through interface
            hints.reflection().registerType(TypeReference.of("java.util.Collection"),
                    builder -> builder.withMembers(MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_METHODS));
            hints.reflection().registerType(TypeReference.of("java.util.Collections$EmptyList"),
                    builder -> builder.withMembers(MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_METHODS));
```